# Angular Fade In Out animation not working

Tags: html, css, angular, animation, angular-animations

I want to achieve a simple animation using the angular animation package

The idea is to just transition from opacity 0 to opacity 1 to give the fade sensation.

I could make it work for another properties like height and display, but not opacity.

this is the little animation

```
trigger('fadeInOut', [
  state('initial', style({
    'display': 'none',
    'opacity': '0'
  })),
  state('final', style({
    'opacity': '1'
  })),
  transition('initial <=> final', [
    animate('200ms')
  ])
])
```

And the trigger in the HTML as follows:

```
<div class="tu-plus-wrapper__content" [@fadeInOut]="privateMode">
    <div class="tu-plus-wrapper__content__points">{{points | number}}</div>
    <div class="tu-plus-wrapper__content__text">Puntos</div>
</div>
```

it sits upon a property called privateMode, which changes depending on a toggle button.

But it just does nothing, display works well but looks really rough transition, I would like to use opacity to have a better UI.

Any animation junkie out there?

Answer (score 0):

I believe opacity takes a number argument not a string remove the '' around the value your passing the opacity property like so:

```
trigger('fadeInOut', [
 state('initial', style({
  'display': 'none',
  'opacity': 0
 })),
 state('final', style({
  'opacity': 1
 })),
 transition('initial <=> final', [
  animate('200ms')
 ])
])
```

Comment: @juanca Did you end up resolving your issue?

Comment: Actually I could not make it work, I ended up just using ngClass and triggering with a boolean

Answer (score 0):

Your animation is correct and works properly. The problem in my opinion sits in your toggle logic.
See here for an exemple : https://angular.io/guide/animations